# Read excel file from a stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, file-upload, filestream

I need a way to read a Excel file from a stream. It doesn't seem to work with the ADO.NET way of doing things.

The scenario is that a user uploads a file through a FileUpload and i need to read some values from the file and import to a database.

For several reasons I **can't** save the file to disk, and there is no reason to do so either.

So, anyone know of a way to read a Excel file from a FileUpload stream?

Comment: Have a look at this SO solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/13978464/1242061

Answer (score 15):

It seems i found a soultion to the problem myself.

http://www.codeplex.com/ExcelDataReader

This library seems to work nicely and it takes a stream to read the excel file.

```
ExcelDataReader reader = new ExcelDataReader(ExcelFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);
```

Comment: The current syntax appears to be:
IExcelDataReader reader = new ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(ExcelFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);   

Or for 97-2003 format files IExcelDataReader reader = new ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(ExcelFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);

Answer (score 6):

This can be done easily with [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus).

```
//the excel sheet as byte array (as example from a FileUpload Control)
byte[] bin = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

//gen the byte array into the memorystream
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bin))
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
{
    //get the first sheet from the excel file
    ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    //loop all rows in the sheet
    for (int i = sheet.Dimension.Start.Row; i <= sheet.Dimension.End.Row; i++)
    {
        //loop all columns in a row
        for (int j = sheet.Dimension.Start.Column; j <= sheet.Dimension.End.Column; j++)
        {
            //do something with the current cell value
            string currentCellValue = sheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this work with Multipart stream? I don't want to read file contents into memory

Answer (score 4):

[SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can do it:

```
SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbookSet().Workbooks.OpenFromStream(stream);
```

You can try it for yourself with the [free evaluation](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: +1 I've just had a need to do this myself and was happy to see that SSG can do it as I've already got a licence for it - saves me any messing about!

Answer (score 1):

I use [ClosedXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/) nuget package to read excel content from stream. It has a constructor overload in `XLWorkbook` class which takes stream pointing to an excel file (aka workbook).

imported namespace at the top of your code file:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
```

Source code:

```
var stream = /*obtain the stream from your source*/;
if (stream.Length != 0)
{
    //handle the stream here
    using (XLWorkbook excelWorkbook = new XLWorkbook(stream))
    {
        var name = excelWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Name;
        //do more things whatever you like as you now have a handle to the entire workbook.
        var firstRow = excelWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Row(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com) has an [excel component](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/infragisticsexcel.aspx) that can read an excel file from a stream.

I'm using it in a project here and it works well.

Also the open source [myXls component](http://myxls.in2bits.org/wiki/MainPage.ashx) could easily be modified to support this. The XlsDocument contstructor only supports loading from a file given by a file name, but it works by creating a FileStream and then reading the Stream, so changing it to support loading from streams should be trivial.

Edit:
I see that you found a solution but I just wanted to note that I updated the source code for the component so that it now can read an excel file directly from a stream. :-)