# Save workbook into a stream instead of a file

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

Is it possible (and how) to save an **Microsoft Excel** workbook into a **stream** instead of a file?

what I have now is:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
.......
workbook.SaveAs(Filename: fileName, FileFormat: XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
```

But both documentation as intellisense give me no clue how to put this in a `stream` and write it with a `BinaryWriter` e.g. to output it via the browser.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560435/read-excel-file-from-a-stream

Comment: @0A0D thanks for the tip ;) but I don't have a stream like in that question ( the OP has a stream from an upload) So that question is quite the opposite, still very a helpful reference.

Comment: Hoping that something in that answer will pique your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office Automation provides an API to control tge office UI. It does not provide a way to store a workbook to a stream. To do that you need something lower level like a binary writer (POI) or Office Open XML SDK.

Comment: The irony is, I just switched from Office Open XML to PO-Excel and never realized this would be an issue. sigh :(....

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne, why in tbe world would you swith to automation if ooxml was working for you?  Automation should be the absolute last resort and in many cases is a huge problem (ie ASP.NET).

Comment: Because I am stupid. And I wanted to know how it worked. Lesson learned. 2 hours wasted.

Comment: @Caspar Kleijne, 2 hours isn't bad at all for that lesson.