# Read data from excel file in c#

Tags: c#, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Excel files from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c)

I'm searching some easy way to read data from excel file. How can I read data from ex. cell 4A? Is it possible? Or I must read dataRow? (If yes, how?)

Extra info: I haven't Microsoft Office, I use Open Office.

Comment: Related questions did not help you?

Answer (score 3):

What version of excel document do you wish to read?

If you don't want to use Office Interop, you are going to need a 3rd party excel reading library.

For Excel 2007/2010 (xlsx) you want EPPlus (GPL) http://epplus.codeplex.com

For Excel 2003 (xls) you want NPOI (Apache License) http://code.google.com/p/npoi/

Answer (score 1):

See this post, [Read excel file from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560435/read-excel-file-from-a-stream).

You could also use OleDb... http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Open XML SDK** to work with excel files (one of the adventeges for you - it doesn't require MS Office to be instaled). Take a look at [it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837.aspx).