# Read XLS document from System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am implementing an interface that has 2 parameters: `(System.IO.Stream input, System.IO.Stream output)`.

If the input stream was originated in an **XLSX** file I would be using `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument` to read the document.

If it was **CSV** it would be even easier: `StreamReader.ReadLine()`.

However the stream is coming from an **XLS** file and I am not quite sure how to read it correctly.

I was trying to figure out whether `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` can read streams but I'm not sure it is possible.

Is there any way to analyse an XLS file provided via `System.IO.Stream`?

Comment: Is someone passing a stream to your application? Or are you creating the stream in your application?

Comment: Someone is passing the stream, I have no control over it.

Comment: So, just to clarify, someone is passing a spreadsheetdocument object to you if the file is XLS. Correct?

Comment: It is a binary file.  Reading it and understanding it are not the same.  Write the binary to disc and then open it with Excel.  I know it seems wasteful but it I don't think Interop.Excel will accept a stream.

Comment: You might be able to open the stream using the Excel ODBC driver.  Search MSDN for Excel ODBC driver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read excel file from a stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560435/read-excel-file-from-a-stream)

Comment: @Blam, I know I can save the stream to disc and then open it with Excel, but this is something I am trying to avoid. Cannot find how it can be done with the Excel ODBC driver so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer. It involves a new library (exceldatareader).

[Read excel file from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560435/read-excel-file-from-a-stream)

Comment: Thanks, Chuck, but as it was mentioned in the question I am familiar with the `SpreadsheetDocument` solution - it can be used if the Excel file is in XML format (they usually have extension XLSX). I need to open an XLS file (Excel 97-2003 Workbook).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification (I must have a reading comprehension problem today). I updated the answer for you.

Comment: I had hopes for a standard solution but it seems there is no standard way of doing it. I'll check the suggested solution, thanks.

Comment: I won't be able to use the Excel Data Reader library on the project, so I am going to upvote but not accept the answer. I'll just have to find another solution or a workaround that doesn't involve 3rd party libraries. Thanks.