# Excel uploading error in the live version ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, stream

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, I have used an action to give the user to select the excel file that he wants to upload. Then he submits it and uploaded it to the database.

This works when I run the application from Visual Studio. I have tried in the debug mode.

But when I apply this to the live version, It get an error. User Cannot Upload the excel to the application.

Does any one know the reason why this happens?

This is my controller code

```
 public ActionResult ImportKPIDetails(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile) {

   if (excelFile.ContentLength == 0 || excelFile == null) {
     ViewBag.Error = "Please select the excel file";
     return View("KPIDetails");
   } else {

     if (excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx")) {
       string path = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/" + excelFile.FileName);
       if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) System.IO.File.Delete(path);
       excelFile.SaveAs(path);
       ExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/ExcelFile/") + path;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;

       List < KPIUploadVM > xcel = new List < KPIUploadVM > ();

       for (int i = 2; i <= range.Rows.Count; i++) {
         try {

           KPIUploadVM kpi = new KPIUploadVM();
           int EmpNo = int.Parse(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) range.Cells[i, 1]).Text);
           var EmpId = (from c in db.CreateEmployee where c.EmpNo == EmpNo select c.Id).First();
           kpi.EmpId = EmpId;
           kpi.KPI = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) range.Cells[i, 2]).Text;
           kpi.Year = int.Parse(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range) range.Cells[i, 3]).Text);

           KPIUploadVM Udata = new KPIUploadVM();
           Udata.EmpId = kpi.EmpId;
           Udata.KPI = kpi.KPI;
           Udata.Year = kpi.Year;

           xcel.Add(Udata);
         } catch (Exception) {
           workbook.Close(true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
           System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
           application.Quit();
           ViewBag.Error = "Error in " + i + " record";
           return View("KPIDetails");
         }

       }
       if (xcel != null) {

         try {

           foreach(var item in xcel) {
             int empID = item.EmpId;
             string Kpi = item.KPI;
             int year = item.Year;

             MainKPI e = new MainKPI();
             e.EmpId = empID;
             e.KPI = Kpi;
             e.Year = year;
             e.Status = true;
             e.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;

             dbs.MainKPI.Add(e);
             dbs.SaveChanges();

           }
         } catch (Exception ex) {

           ViewBag.Error = "Error " + ex;
         }

         TempData["msg"] = "success";
         return View("KPIDetails", xcel);
       } else {

       }

       return View("KPIDetails");
     } else {
       ViewBag.Error = "Selected excel file not supported";
       return View("KPIDetails");
     }
   }

 }
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting? As an aside, I would not recommend using Microsoft Office.Interop on a Live Web Server. There are libraries that read Excel files without requiring Office to be installed.  I wrote my own, which is also capable of reading from a `Stream` so no need to save to the server's hard drive before reading.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Hi. Can you show me an example for this ?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560435/read-excel-file-from-a-stream) is old but contains links that should get you started. As I said, I ended up writing my own library, but if you search you will find free libraries that will do the job.